# Particle system replaced by black boxes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, particle-system

I used 7 particle systems to create black holes in unity. 
In unity editor the black hole works perfect but when I try to build this game into my android device , the particle systems get replaced by black boxes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqenQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOUVj.png)

Comment: Is there any question?

Answer (score 0):

Select mobile friendly shaders/materials as your shader type this should fix your problem

if the particle effect your using is using a custom shader you will have to change its shader code to get it to work on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Shader to Mobile>particles>Additive . (and don't forget to reassign particle texture).